# How do I do an exact string match using gsub in R?

Tags: r, string, gsub

```
raw = c("MOUNTAIN VIEW","MOUNTAIN")
x = gsub("MOUNTAIN", "MOUNTAIN VIEW", raw, ignore.case = TRUE)

Current output: "MOUNTAIN VIEW VIEW" "MOUNTAIN VIEW"  
Desired output:  "MOUNTAIN VIEW" "MOUNTAIN VIEW"
```

I only want to replace the 2nd entry in the raw data `MOUNTAIN` with `MOUNTAIN VIEW`. The first entry in raw data is already correct. But when I do `gsub` it replaces both the occurrences of `MOUNTAIN` with `MOUNTAIN VIEW`. Can anyone help me find a way to get around that?

I tried `\\b` but it didn't work and I understand why. Is there any thing else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**anchors**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret) instead here to match the entire string:

```
sub('^MOUNTAIN$', 'MOUNTAIN VIEW', raw, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] "MOUNTAIN VIEW" "MOUNTAIN VIEW"
```

If you desire, you can also use a capturing group and backreference it inside the replacement call:

```
sub('^(MOUNTAIN)$', '\\1 VIEW', raw, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `agrep` -returns vector indices, so you can easily assign a value by using `subscripts`:

```
raw[agrep("MOUNTAIN", raw)] <- "MOUNTAIN VIEW" 
raw
[1] "MOUNTAIN VIEW" "MOUNTAIN VIEW"
```